# Edit the default login.html felogin plugin in my own fluid extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, felogin

I use typo 10 and add the Felogin extension, but I want to customize / edit the login template as I want it in my own fluid extension

I have tried adding

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
  templateFile = EXT: my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/Pages/Login.html
}
```

but instead the default template appears. is there still less code?

Comment: This looks correct. Where or how did you include that? Are the TypoScript files included correctly in your template (include static from extensions)? Refreshed or disabled cache?

Comment: I just added the script in the setup.typoscript page where i want to add felogin plugin. 
I refreshed the cache

but instead the default template appears

Comment: Is your setup.typoscript included correctly? You can check all settings with help of the TypoScript Object Browser. Go to your template and choose "TypoScript Object Browser" in the dropdown at the top. Select "Browse Setup" and double check "plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.templateFile".

Comment: when i edit template that page for include static from extensions. but there are no items available for felogin. but i have intalled & active  Frontend Login for Website Users extensions

is that the problem?

Comment: for this (plugin.tx_felogin_pi 1.template File) is correct. I checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use new Fluid templates with feLogin, you have to add this Typoscript Setup :

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.1 = EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Templates/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to look if the feature toggle is set correctly.
If you activated "Extbase" for felogin, the customization is done different (with `plugin.xxx.view.templateRootpaths` like in other Extbase/Fluid extensions).

Just take a look at the TypoScript code of Fluid and the small documentation of the change: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.2/Feature-88102-FrontendLoginViaFluidAndExtbase.html

Comment: after I activate "Extbase" for felogin. appear
ERROR: Content Element with uid "26" and type "felogin_login" has no rendering definition!

although I have copied the default file felogin/Resources/Private template   to my fluid extension and some edited at login.html

have solution?

Can I put it in [templateFile] = EXT: myExtension / Resources / Private / Templates / ContentElements / Login / Login.html ?

Comment: @FiqihFadillah After activating the Extbase Feature Toggle, you need to insert the FeLogin plugin again, it's not the same plugin